# simplePagination scroll to top

Tags: pagination

I am using the simplePagination script on my site, with following js:

```
var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
        var o = $.extend({
            items: 1,
            itemsOnPage: 1,
            pages: 0,
            displayedPages: 5,
            edges: 2,
            currentPage: 0,
            useAnchors: false,
            hrefTextPrefix: '#page-',
            hrefTextSuffix: '',
            prevText: '<',
            nextText: '>',
            ellipseText: '&hellip;',
            ellipsePageSet: true,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            listStyle: '',
            labelMap: [],
            selectOnClick: true,
            nextAtFront: false,
            invertPageOrder: false,
            useStartEdge : true,
            useEndEdge : true,
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                // Callback triggered when a page is clicked
                // Page number is given as an optional parameter
            },
            onInit: function() {
                // Callback triggered immediately after initialization
            }
        }, options || {});
```

(and more code)

And at the bottom of the page, I also added

```
    $(".wrapper .item").slice(1).hide();
    $('#pagination').pagination({

        // Total number of items present
        // in wrapper class
        items: 3,

        // Items allowed on a single page
        itemsOnPage: 1, 
        onPageClick: function (noofele) {
            $(".wrapper .item").hide()
                .slice(1*(noofele-1),
                1+ 1* (noofele - 1)).show();
        }
    });
```

I would like to have it jump to the top of the page when clicking on a "next" or "page number", so I tried to insert this, but it doesn't do the trick (it jumps to the top but always shows the same content - not the content of the number I am clicking on):

```
onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0, left: 0,  
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
```

Can anyone let me know what to insert and where in order to have the jump to the top, please? Thanks.